# Haskell Dividing a list in two: even and odd numbers

Tags: haskell, zip

I'm driving myself crazy with this simple exercice. I just want to divide a list by two, separating even and odd numbers. My code is the following:

```
module Proyecto1 where

separarPorPosicion :: [a] ->([a],[a])
separarPorPosicion xs= (pares,impares) where
    pares = [x | (x,y)<- zip xs [1..], even y]
    impares = [x | (x,y)<- zip xs [1..], odd y]
```

The only result I get is the same list I write, the same way I wrote.
I.E, if I enter [1,2,3,4,5,6], the result will be [1,2,3,4,5,6] the same way.

This is what I'm writing in GHCi:

```
*Proyecto1> (1,2,3,4,5,6)
(1,2,3,4,5,6)
*Proyecto1> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: How are you running this function? GHCi or as part of the bigger program? Can you post the code that calls the function and the result it produces?

Comment: This function works the way you expected on GHCi version 8.0.1: `separarPorPosicion [1,2,3,4] = ([2,4],[1,3])`. What's the problem?

Comment: It's all the code I have. Im just learning and begginning at a very low level. I'm running GHCi. Thanks!

Comment: @AJFarmar i don't know what's going on then, cause the way im trying it doesn't work D:

Comment: @DiegoFerrari Then post the way you're trying it in your question. If we don't know what the problem is then we can't help. Use the 'edit' button to add information.

Comment: https://ibb.co/jddRpo here is the environment and the code running in a screenshot

Comment: @DiegoFerrari Please *write* that in the *question*, not in a screenshot. What you're writing in the REPL is the issue, and if you write that in your question, I'll answer it.

Comment: @DiegoFerrari Since you haven't done so, I've edited your question for you to include the text in the screenshot. Please do not use screenshots in future questions.

Comment: It's possible to define this function by composing two functions from the standard library: `partition even`

Comment: @MarkSeemann: That partitions into even and odd *elements*; this function partitions by even and odd *indices*. You could still use `partition` of course, like: `(fmap snd *** fmap snd) . partition (even . fst) . zip [1..]`

Answer (score 5):

Your code is absolutely correct, well done. It's how you're calling it. Let's have a look at your GHCi:

```
*Proyecto1> (1,2,3,4,5,6)
(1,2,3,4,5,6)
*Proyecto1> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

When you write something in GHCi, you're asking it to evaluate that. So, when you write `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` you're just saying, "What is the value of `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`?" **You're not using your function!**

You should write this:

```
*Proyecto1> separarPorPosicion [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
([2,4,6], [1,3,5,7])
```

This is telling GHCi to use the function `separarPorPosicion` on the value `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`. Before, you were not doing this.

---

A side note: You also wrote `(1,2,3,4,5,6)`. It's important to know that this is not a **list**, of type `[Int]`, but a **tuple**, of type `(Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)`. You cannot therefore write `separarPorPosicion (1,2,3,4,5,6)`. This will not work.

Comment: i know about the tuple of type int, but i was so tired of trying everything came in my mind... How can I be so clueless? Thank you very much for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

You say

> if I enter [1,2,3,4,5,6], the result will be [1,2,3,4,5,6] the same way

But what you should enter is a function call:

```
ghci> separarPorPosicion [1,2,3,4,5,6]
([2,4,6],[1,3,5])
```

Another way to write your function could be:

```
separarPorPosicion xs = case xs of
  o:e:ys -> let (es,os) = separarPorPosicion ys in (e:es,o:os)
  [o] -> ([],[o])
  [] -> ([],[])
```

Comment: Your alternate solution can have one fewer cases with a bit of cleverness: `case xs of y:ys -> let (os, es) = separarPorPosicion ys in (y:es, os); [] -> ([], [])`. The even positions in a list are the odd positions in its tail and vice versa.

Comment: @DanielWagner that’s certainly true. One can also replace the second case with `os -> ([],os)` but I thought that stepping through the list two-at-a-time would make things more obvious, even if it means a bit more work and loc are necessary.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! I was completely stubborn in the code and didnt pay attention to the call.